# Showing the legend in GeoPandas when color is given by value

Tags: geopandas, legend, color, plot

I'm **coloring** the entities of a GeoDataFrame by the column 'Color'. This column has been created to plot the **different continents** with different colors, so all the countries belonging to the same continent have the same value in this column.

[image]

Besides, I'd like to add a **legend** to the plot that reflects the different continents.

I thought that this could be done indicating too the column to plot and the column from which to pick the color, but since `geopandas.plot()` specify what follows, I do not know how to achieve it:

*legend: bool (default False)
Plot a legend. Ignored if no column is given, or if color is given.*

I understand then that **plotting entities by a color column and adding a legend seems not to be compatible in a geopandas plot**. So, does exist another way of doing this?

Here I show an example based on one of the *geopandas datasets*:

```
# Creating geoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
gdf.sort_values(['continent'], inplace=True)

color_dict = {'Africa':'orange', 'Antarctica':'white', 'Asia':'pink', 
              'Europe':'green', 'North America':'brown',
              'Oceania':'blue', 'Seven seas (open ocean)':'gray',
              'South America':'red'}

gdf['Color'] = gdf['continent'].map(color_dict)
```

**Plotting** based on the column 'Color':

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
gdf.plot(column='continent', color=gdf['Color'], legend=True, ax=ax)
plt.axis('off')
```

[image]
I have already tried to indicate the color **as a list** once I've specified the  column 'continent', but it has no effects on the plot:

```
gdf.plot(column='continent', color=gdf['Color'].unique().tolist(),
         legend=True, ax=ax)
```

What I'm seeking is that the following would work:

```
gdf.plot(column='continent', color=gdf['Color'],
         legend=True, ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by defining **cmap**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# Creating geoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

color_dict = {'Africa':'orange', 'Antarctica':'white', 'Asia':'pink', 
              'Europe':'green', 'North America':'brown',
              'Oceania':'blue', 'Seven seas (open ocean)':'gray',
              'South America':'red'}


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
gdf.plot(ax=ax, column="continent", legend=True, cmap=colors.ListedColormap(list(color_dict.values())))
plt.axis('off')
```

[image]

Comment: Great! And it can also be used via 'explore' method --> check:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71128806/13151511